# Some browsers wont update hidden input when submitting form

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, html

I have a classifieds website, and in the **index.html** there is a form.
This forms target is set to an iframe, also in **index.html**.

```
<form id="main" name="main" action="search.php" target="iframe" method="get">
```

I use `body onload` to submit the form when page is loaded:

```
 <body onload='submit_form();'>
```

The results are as I said displayed in the **iframe**, and I use MySql Limit to create paging.
I display a "next" and "previous" to the user: (all this is displayed inside the iframe, so I call the function on the parent page like below)

```
<a onclick='window.parent.page_upd(2)'>Page 2</a>

function page_upd(p){
  document.getElementById('page').value=p;
  document.forms['main'].submit();
}

<input type="hidden" id="page" value="1">
```

As you see I set a hidden input inside **index.html** to the **pagenumber** I wish the user to view, then I **submit** the form, and in the action (search.php) I fetch the page and display accordingly:

```
 //search.php
  $page = $_GET['page'];
```

The paging works in all browsers, so going to different pages works.
But when **actually clicking a search result**, and going to a completely different link (show_ad.php), and the hitting back, the user is taken back to the first page of the search results.

In other words, "**page**" is set to 1 again.
But not in all browsers, FF and even IE6 "**remembers**" the "page" value and there it is still '2' for example (for the second page), so the form submits showing the second page.

In Chrome and Opera however, page is set to '1'.

Anybody know why the "page" inputs value is set to 1 again when hitting back in browser?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is related to browser caching. Some browsers seem to load the page as if you made a fresh load of that page while other browsers still take the right page out of the cache.

A workaround forthis could be to include an own back button in your application which will send the user to the correct page.

Comment: Then I would have to pass along variables, and it would mean too much work. Any other solution?

Comment: an easier approch is to store the page number in a session variable (i.e. $_SESSION['page_nbr']), when the page gets called you automatically switch to the page the user last visited in that session

Answer (score 0):

Your input field needs a `name` attribute to use as the param name when submitting.  The `id` attribute serves only as an *identifier* to find the element on the page.

```
<input type="hidden" id="page" name="page" value="1">
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: ah, ok... I just read that it was submitting but "losing" the value thus this answer made sense at the time.

Answer (score 0):

That's because the page doesn't load again, therefor no onLoad()

Comment: The problem is that body onload triggers when hitting back from a completely different link. This causes "page" to be set to 1.